# Oracle spool UTF-8 without BOM at beginning of file

Tags: oracle, utf-8, byte-order-mark, spool

I spool data from Oracle to a csv-file.

When I open the csv in editor all signs are shown correctly.
But in Excel or Kofax the file special characters (e.g. ß or ö)
are not displayed correct.

Could it be an option to select the missing BOM characters to
the beginning of the file? If yes, how should I do that? 
If not, is there an other possibility to do it?

Best regards
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use SQL*Plus on Windows to spool the data.

In this case SQL*Plus inherits the codepage from `cmd.exe`. This can be interrogated with command `chcp` and is most likely [CP850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) or [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

Spooled files are written in this encoding. While CP850 or CP437 are very common for console, they are hardly supported by any applications or editors.

Change your codepage to [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) for example. However, you must also tell Oracle (i.e. the Oracle drivers) that you are using Windows-1252, this is done by `NLS_LANG` environment value:

```
chcp 1252
set NLS_LANG=GERMAN_GERMANY.WE8MSWIN1252
```

Then launch your SQL*Plus and everything in spooled files should be fine.